# JSON Performance in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, mongoid, activemodel

I'm running a query on my index action in a Rails app, and if you look at the logs it's pretty fast:

```
Started GET "/apartments?within=-74.01798248291016%2C40.746346606483826%2C-73.8943862915039%2C40.79314877043915&per_page=500" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-01 16:58:21 +0200
Processing by ApartmentsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"within"=>"-74.01798248291016,40.746346606483826,-73.8943862915039,40.79314877043915", "per_page"=>"500"}
MONGODB (228ms) development['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"apartments", "query"=>{:status=>"available", :coordinates=>{"$within"=>{"$box"=>[[-74.01798248291016, 40.746346606483826], [-73.8943862915039, 40.79314877043915]]}}}, "fields"=>{:neighborhood_id=>0}}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (445ms) development['apartments'].find({:status=>"available", :coordinates=>{"$within"=>{"$box"=>[[-74.01798248291016, 40.746346606483826], [-73.8943862915039, 40.79314877043915]]}}}, {:neighborhood_id=>0}).limit(500).sort([[:qs, :desc]])
Completed 200 OK in 9737ms (Views: 8816.0ms)
```

If the DB query only takes 445ms, why does the JSON take almost 10 seconds to render and get sent back over the wire?

Is there a faster way to render the `@apartments` collection to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Use a different JSON serializer?

https://rubygems.org/gems/oj